# Derivations and ideals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a regular local ring and $I$ and ideal of $R$. If $D$ is a derivation of $R$, let
$$\lambda_D:I/I^2\to R/I$$
be the composition of the restriction of $D$ to $I$ and the quotient map $R\to R/I$. It is a morphism of $R$-modules. What are the conditions on $I$ that imply that the map
$D\to\text{Hom}(I/I^2,R/I)$ sending $\lambda_D$ to $D$ is surjective ?

I know that it is true if $I$ is generated by a regular sequence. Are there other examples ?

Comment: Are you sure this is true for regular sequences? For example, $R=k[[t]], I=t^2R$.

Comment: @Mohan you are right. I meant a subsequence of a maximal regular sequence. And obviously I have to take $\text{Hom}(I/I^2,R/I)$ instead oh $\text{Hom}(I,R/I)$.

Comment: Under mild restrictions, the map is surjective if and only if $Ext^1_{R/I}(\Omega^1_{R/I},R/I)=0$. I do not know what you meant by a subsequence of a maximal regular sequence.

Comment: I meant a subsequence of a regular sequence that generates the maximal ideal.

Answer (score 0):

$R$ is an $A$-algebra and $I \subseteq R$ is an ideal. If the natural map $\pi : R/I^2 \to R/I$ has a right inverse, then for every $R$-module $M$ such that $IM = 0$, the restriction map $\text{Der}_{R/A}(M) \to \text{Hom}_R(I/I^2, M)$ is surjective. Here, $\text{Der}_{R/A}(M)$ denotes the set of $A$-linear derivations from $R$ to $M$.

Comment: Thank you for these examples